# Why does Eclipse keep defaulting my Run config as Javabean?

Tags: android, eclipse, javabeans

I am using Helios Service Release 1, with the Android SDK 2.3.1 API 9 r2. Everytime I create a new Android project, and got to run it always gives me an error as it is trying to run it as a Javabean! In order to run it I have to either add the project as an Android app in the Run config. or right click on the Project and select run as Android App.. Anyone have this problem or can suggest something I can try to change the default?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use Android SDK, but I solved this problem in my Eclipse instance by uninstalling Visual Editor component. 
(e.g. like this, depending on Eclipse version: Menu->Help/Install New Software/What is already installed/Installed Software)

Comment: Thanks Marian that worked a treat!!I had installed the VE a while back and used it with no issues.. when i started using Android SDK I never thought it would be related to VE. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your run configuration is messed up and you need to configure it properly.

Go to `Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching`

and check what you have under `Launch Operation`.

Comment: Hi @darioo - thanks for you help. I have checked the settings and can not see anything which forces my default to be a javabean. I have check and tried alot of possible options and nothing seems to work.. I think something must have gone wrong in my initial setup since i google'd this issue and seems only me having it. I am thinking of re installing the android plugin or even a fresh install of eclipse if that doesn't work! But thanks once again for your help :)