# How can I remove JavaBeans from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, javabeans

When I click the run/debug button on eclipse it tries to activate it using javaBeans.
The problem that I deleted JavaBeans. Another thing is when I choose run/debug As... I have only the option of javaBeans despite the fact that I have regular java and android installed on my computer.

How can I fix it? In other words how can I get rid of this javaBeans?

**[SOLVED]**
For all those who stumble upon this thread. You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950767/why-does-eclipse-keep-defaulting-my-run-config-as-javabean)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Eclipse keep defaulting my Run config as Javabean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950767/why-does-eclipse-keep-defaulting-my-run-config-as-javabean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who stumble upon this thread. You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950767/why-does-eclipse-keep-defaulting-my-run-config-as-javabean)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem, but instead of pressing the "run" button, press the little drop down triangle next to it. This will bring up the run configurations. From here you can delete and edit existing configurations (such as your java beans) one, and create new ones (using different configurations).

Comment: The default run\debug config is javaBean. In case I delete the javaBean config and then press run\debug it creates by default javaBean config and try to run it with it (of course it doesn't run)

Comment: You can create a different type of configuration in the same place where you delete the javaBean config. It is confusing that Eclipse just does it automatically the first time - very confusing for first timers. Let me know you go.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to delete the javaBean LAUNCHER and not the specific configuration. Do you or anybody else know how to do it?

Comment: Sorry - I did misunderstand you. Maybe posting a screen shot will help.